# Custom bottom app bar in metro applications

Tags: c#, xaml

apologize if i am  wrong, i am developing metro apps using windows8 preview release using C#.
As we all know we can create bottom app bars.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx

By using below code we can get upload app bar

```
<Button x:Name="BTNUpload" AutomationProperties.Name="upload" Style="{StaticResource UploadAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
```

my question is how to create custom app bars?

Answer (score 0):

Like they say in msdn: just customize and add that code in your XAML.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
<AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource RemoveAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource RefreshAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource HelpAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: Thanks Mualig, Can you please explain how to customize and put our own image for that app button