# Custom Bottom app bars in metro app using C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

Apologize if I'm wrong, I'm developing metro app using C# and XAML, As we all know we can create Bottom app bars in metro app using below code

```
<Button x:Uid="Uploadall" x:Name="BTNUpload" AutomationProperties.Name="upload all" Style="{StaticResource UploadAppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

This will create an "upload all" button in bottom app bar, my question is how to create a custom app bar with my own image on it, By this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211050/custom-bottom-app-bar-in-metro-appications) i came to know that we can customize it, Can anyone explains me how to customize app button,Please help me Thanks In-advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, I found answer for my question that we can add a PNG image to an App button, check the code below

```
<Button x:Name="BTNPintoStart" AutomationProperties.Name = "Pin to start" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" FontSize="15" Click="BTNPintoStart_Click">
<Button.Content>
<Image Source="../../Resources/Assets/AppBar/appbar_pin.png"/>
</Button.Content>
</Button>
```

If you want to set name from resource you can do that from C# by

```
AutomationProperties.SetName(BTNPintoStart,resourceloader.GetString("KeyName/Content"));
```

If it works for you,Please mark as answer, where i can useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to customize a button. It all depends on how you want to customize it. In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346957/how-do-i-set-a-custom-button-background-for-a-metro-app-for-all-states/11347267#11347267) I answered how to do that so that you can represent each button state with your own image. You can change multiple properties of a button to customize it, you can customize it by changing its style, template or content.

Answer (score 0):

The default AppBarButtonStyle doesn't use images but font gylphs (notice the Content property in the style). This question [How to find icons for app bar in metro windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574829/how-to-find-icons-for-app-bar-in-metro-windows-8) has some sources for those icons.

Creating Application Bar Buttons with images is actually quite a pain due to for some unknown reason the developers of this xaml stack didn't include Opactiy Mask, so you'll need multiple images. I'd recommend sticking with glyphs.